# Get the current taxonomy product category title in woocommerce

Tags: plugins

I am wanting to show the current taxonomy product category title in the single product page.

The code below works, but returns all product categories. I need some help singling out the current category.

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);

    $count = count($terms); 
    if ($count > 0) {

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<div style="direction:rtl;">';
        echo 'Category: ' . $term->name;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

After a few hours of experimenting and searching, you guys are my last hope for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`get_the_term_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list)

```
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'product_cat', '<div style="direction:rtl;">', '</div>', '' );
```

The system of displaying 1 category title on a single product page fails if you start adding the item to multiple categories.

I went crazy once on a project where a client was adding portfolio items to two categories and yet somehow wanted me to show the 'right' category title depending. That project led me to create the [Radio Buttons for Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/) plugin to restrict users to a single term in certain taxonomies.

Comment: Just as informational addition using `get_the_term_list()` is just what `$product->get_categories()` does.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks for taking the time to help. Both solutions work for a single category.

Comment: @ialocin So it does! Learn something new every day.

Comment: My life motto :)

Answer (score 2):

In most themes I know this is standard, but yours might differ. Below code is from the [`meta.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/release-2-0-20/templates/single-product/meta.php) file, which is responsible for showing the meta data - categories, tags - in woocommerce.

**Code:**

```
    <?php
            $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
            echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $size, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
    ?>
```

---

**Edit:**

I gave an extended answer to this problem some time ago:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113825/22534

Comment: Thanks, ialocin. This code returns all categories. It's not what I am looking for. I am looking for the single category you are in currently to be displayed.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you, see my edit. @Kapitol

Comment: Your solution does show a single category, but it still is not the current category. You addressed the issue of having multiple top level categories by saying "won't work if a product has multiple main-/toplevel-categories, or at least won't show them all;"

Comment: You're on a single product page, if a product has more then one category of the top level, how can there be a single current category? @Kapitol

Comment: Good question. Could be it's impossible. Maybe it is a breadcrumbs type of solution. Below is what I wanted to achieve.

In a category page it lists the current category you are in. Clicking on a product within that category takes you to the product. I want a title stating you came from the previous category.

Comment: I know, it's impossible with out additional logic. BTW breadcrumbs have the same problem, how should they know what the right trail is. Normally one is chosen, depending on how the function behind sorts terms. Your problem on the other hand can be solved by passing the a value over to the single product page from the category page you come from, but that would be a *completely* different from the question you asked. You should look into that and ask a new one. This one in my mind is solved or unanswerable. @Kapitol