# Taxonomy term breadcrumb; how?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, hierarchical, terms, breadcrumb

Given a taxonomy term (perhaps in a taxonomy*.php template) how to construct a breadcrumb going up the full ancestry of the term?

Is there any shorter way other than a "brute-force" loop to query current term's parent -> query term's parent -> query term's parent etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) for this:

```
get_ancestors( $term_id, 'taxonomy' );
```

Of course this will only work on hierarchical elements. Additionally, this will only work reasonably well if only one term per level is assigned, take a look at my comment [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123952/get-the-current-taxonomy-product-category-title-in-woocommerce/123958#comment174520_123958) and my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113825/22534) to get a little bit deeper insight into that.

Comment: OK get_ancestors() helps a bit, but only gets IDs. Is there nothing shorter / more to-the-point for this? I was hoping since wp_list_categories() exists, WP should also have something like get_term_breadcrumb() or wtvr... I guess not then?

Comment: There is [get_the_term_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list), but it doesn't get ancestors. What wordpress should additionally have is up for debate I guess. Have you read the answer I linked? There I pretty much explain how to do what you want. @xyphenor